# display the most recent input lines entered by the user

Tags: c++

I was asked to design and implement a C/C++ program that will
serve as a rudimentary command line interpreter (shell). 
the requirement is:
The command "hlist " will display the most recent input lines entered by the user
(along with the associated sequence number). An example of partial "hlist" output:

```
197 cd /user/cse410/Projects
198 curr
199 dtae
200 date
```

I would like to know how to store the history so that I could have them display, or any other suggestions to solve this question?

Comment: How about an array?

Comment: use a stl vector

Comment: How about a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)?

Comment: plain vector could suffer when it reaches the maximum amount of lines it can store. as @Someprogrammerdude suggests a circular buffer would be a better choice. If you want to support deletion of some entries (delete command number *n* for instance) I would suggest a list as a starting point.